# Return the index of element using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

So we have an unsorted array where each element is ±1 the next element (|A[i]-A[i+1]|<=1). Given an element, k, return the index of k in the array A if found.

This is what I came up with:

```
 def find(x,k,z):
    if(len(x) == 1 and x[0] != k):
        return -1
    mid = len(x)//2
    if x[mid] == k:
        return mid + z
    elif abs(x[mid] - k) <= 1:
        return find(x[:mid],k,mid+z)
    else:
        return find(x[mid:],k,mid+z)
```

This is the array I used x = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; the code seems to work for every element but 6 and 2, where it returns -1.

Comment: There is no way to binary search on this. You need to check both left and right of mid if element isn't at index mid. Then check return value of left and right and if one of them is note -1 return it. If both are -1 return -1.

Comment: The goal is to try to do this in O(log n ) times.

Comment: I am quite sure that binary search (in this form at least) does not guarantee correct results. With divide and conquer, you can still aim for logarithmic time complexity using the fact that the difference between 2 adjacent elements is at most 1. At each step, look at the length of the sub array and the value at its first index. If the difference between that value and target is more than the length of the sub array, you can be sure that target is not present in that sub array and return -1 for it without checking the rest of the sub array.

Comment: This cannot be done in better than O(n); consider a list like `[0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]` where the target element to search for is `2`. The `2` could be at any even index in the list, and whenever you don't find it, you only see a 0 or a 1 which tells you nothing about where the 2 is. So if an algorithm doesn't check in O(n) positions, there will still be O(n) positions remaining where the 2 could be.

Comment: @kaya3 since elements cannot change by more than 1, there'll never be a situation where many duplicates increase the size of the array while having no valid result. So you are right about traditional binary search, but we can do a smart partition and recursion...

Comment: @DilumRanatunga There is no smart way to check n/2 indices to find where the number `2` is in that array in less than O(n) time. If you don't check n/2 indices then you don't definitely find it. End of story.

Comment: @kaya3 Could also just use an array full of zeros, except a single 1 somewhere. The condition says `<=1`, not `==1`, and their example array has consecutive threes.

Answer (score 0):

Check for off-by-one errors in your code.
So make sure that you understand how Python list slicing works.
For example,

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(a[:2])
# [0, 1]
print(a[2:])
# [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Which means when you do `x[:mid]` you *exclude* mid element from the end of the list.
But `x[mid:]` you *include* the mid element from the beginning.

Is that what you want to do?

Also as an aside, you may find carrying the left, right indexes into the recursive call easier to understand (and more efficient) than carrying the left offset as `z`. Using left, right helps avoid a bunch of edge case issues in slices and offset arithmetic.

Comment: I tried both including and excluding the mid in my calls but it doesn't change anything I still get an error  for element 6 and 2 where it returns -1

Answer (score 0):

Looks a use case for a discrete kin to the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Motivation).

An implementation clinging on to almost the last bit of information established:

```
def _index_of(values, key, lo, dlo, hi, dhi):
    """ Return index of one occurrence of key in values from lo to hi. 
        Needs abs(values[i] - values[i+1]) <= 1, dlo/dhi == values[lo/hi] and
        (values[lo] < key < values[hi] or values[hi] < key < values[lo]). """
    while True:
        mid = lo + (hi - lo) // 2
        if mid <= lo:
            return -1
        value = values[mid]
        d = value - key
        # print(lo, dlo, mid, d, hi, dhi)
        if d * dlo <= 0:  # key should occur in values[lo:mid+1]
            if d == 0:
                return mid
            hi = mid
            dhi = d
        else:
            lo = mid + 1  # mid + abs(d) would be the only place sign mattered
            dlo = values[lo] - key
            if dlo == 0:
                return lo

def index_of(values, key, z=0):
    """ Return index of one occurrence of key in values, -1 if none. """
    # if values is None:
    #   return -1
    last = len(values) - 1
    if last < z:
        return -1
    dz = values[z] - key
    dl = values[last] - key
    if 0 <= dz * dl:
        if 0 == dz:
            return z
        if 0 == dl:
            return last
        raise "can't guarantee fast result"
    return _index_of(values, key, z, dz, last, dl)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
    def t(x):
        for v in set(x):
            print(v, index_of(x, v))
    t(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach where you look for theoretical maximum and minimum values to determine whether a sublist even capable of holding the search value. With that, you can prune some of the branches.

**The difference between your approach and this:
here, we look at both halves. BUT also short circuit impossible branches to still try achieve O(log n)**

```py
from math import ceil
from typing import List

def th_min_max(x: List[int], li: int, ri: int) -> int:
    """
    Find the theoretical maximum and minimum values
    for all elements between two known "anchor" values
    x is the data, where each abs(x[i] - x[i+1] <= 1)
    li, ri are the indexes of the anchors.
    """
    assert li <= ri
    # these are known values at the anchor locations.
    v1 = x[li]
    v2 = x[ri]
    # so how high/low can the numbers inbetween go?
    # the theoretical maximum is a sustained increase followed by a sustained decrease.
    num_changes = ri - li
    # some of the numbers are used to bridge difference between v1, v2
    remaining = num_changes - abs(v1 - v2)
    assert remaining >= 0, f"The input array does not meet constraints; look at [{li}] --> {v1} and [{ri}] --> {v2}"
    # so now we are look at maximum increase/decrease possible once we've bridged
    # the gap between the two known numbers.
    # half the remaining changes have to be used to 'undo' the initial changes
    # if there is an odd number, the remaining one can be max/min,
    # so use the ceil( ) function to round up.
    biggest_delta = int(ceil(remaining / 2))
    return (min(v1, v2) - biggest_delta, max(v1, v2) + biggest_delta)
```

With the min/max function in hand, we can do a partitioning algorithm:

```py
def find(x: List[int], li: int, ri: int, search: int) -> int:
    """
    finds _some_ index where the search value is found in x 
    between index li and index ri; -1 if not found.
    """
    # first, if li = ri, this is a trivial is this it? question
    if li == ri:
        return li if x[li] == search else -1
    # second, figure out if this range could possibly have the number
    mn, mx = th_min_max(x, li, ri)
    if search < mn:
        # value being looked for _cannot_ be in range [li, ri]
        return -1
    if search > mx:
        # value being looked for _cannot_ be in range [li, ri]
        return -1
    mid = int((li + ri)/2)
    # we ma have to look both ways, but let's start on the
    # side with the anchor value closer to search value
    if abs(x[li] - search) <= abs(search - x[ri]):
        # go left first, then right.
        first = find(x, li, mid, search)
        return first if first >= 0 else find(x, mid + 1, ri, search)
    else:
        # go right first, then left
        first = find(x, mid + 1, ri, search)
        return first if first >= 0 else find(x, li, mid, search)
```

Testing on your input:

```py
d = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

for search in d:
    res = find(d, 0, len(d)-1, search)
    print(search, res, d[res])
```

-->

```
1 0 1
2 1 2
3 6 3
4 5 4
5 11 5
4 5 4
3 6 3
3 6 3
2 1 2
3 6 3
4 5 4
5 11 5
6 12 6
7 13 7
8 14 8
```